# Why is /dev full?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, tmpfs

The /dev.. is full:

```
SERVER:/dev # df -mP /dev
Filesystem         1048576-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
udev                     12042     12042         0     100% /dev
```

There is no files that consume space!

```
SERVER:/dev # find . -ls | sort -r | head -2
2790517    0 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            0 Dec 16 10:04 ./devnull
1490005831    0 -rw-------   1 root     root            0 Dec 16 07:54 ./nul
120387    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           12 Dec 03 05:42 ./disk/by-uuid/xx..foo..xx -> ../../dm-13
SERVER:/dev # du -sm * 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -4
1   shm
0   zero
0   xconsole
0   watchdog
```

swap is used heavily:

```
SERVER:/dev # free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24083      23959        124          0        327      21175
-/+ buffers/cache:       2455      21627
Swap:        10245      10245          0
```

deleted but still used files (?):

```
SERVER:/dev # lsof /dev | grep deleted
su         4510   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6269616128 2689827477 /dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o (deleted)
grep       4512       root    1u   REG    0,14 6269616128 2689827477 /dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o (deleted)
bash       4517   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6269616128 2689827477 /dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o (deleted)
sh         4606   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6269616128 2689827477 /dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o (deleted)
ksh       24134       root    1u   REG    0,14 6329864192 2685851781 /dev/shm/foo5.44m (deleted)
ksh       29209       root    1u   REG    0,14 6269616128 2689827477 /dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o (deleted)
su        29571   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6329864192 2685851781 /dev/shm/foo5.44m (deleted)
grep      29573       root    1u   REG    0,14 6329864192 2685851781 /dev/shm/foo5.44m (deleted)
bash      29578   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6329864192 2685851781 /dev/shm/foo5.44m (deleted)
sh        29694   bar   14u   REG    0,14 6329864192 2685851781 /dev/shm/foo5.44m (deleted)
SERVER:/dev #
```

**My question**: what is using up all the 12 GByte space of "udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw)"?

Comment: Can you paste in the output of `df -h` and `ps u --sort=-pmem`?

Comment: Weird. What other mount points do you have? Any containers or virtualization going on? Also, you ran `du *`: any chance of a dot file? What does `du -x /dev` say?

Comment: Weird indeed. Also, the output of `mount | grep /dev` would help.

Comment: My take: /tmp is mounted/linked to /dev/shm and various tools  and programs use it. But since it is shared with udev, udev is also full (all tmpfses are probably full). Recommendation: Check the other tmpfs and /tmp, mount /tmp to its own tmpfs with a size limit, mount option "size=XXX"

Comment: OP appears (from 'find . -ls | sort -r | head -2' listing) to have files names /dev/devnull and /dev/nul (as opposed to the usual '/dev/null')
Are these perhaps 'sparse' files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shared memory is using the 12GB.

On your Linux release `/dev/shm` part of the `/dev` filesystem (on some releases, it has its own a dedicated file system mounted there).

As shown by `lsof`, the sum is 12 GB:

```
/dev/shm/foo5.44m is 6269616128 bytes   
/dev/shm/kdfoo.a4o is 6269616128 bytes
```

Neither `find` nor `ls` can display theses files because they are unlinked (= their names have been deleted).